# How can i display all the lines that has internet web address in any given file in linux by using regular expression

Tags: grep, cat

Am trying to display all the web address in a given file
Web address like www.gutenberg.org or www.gutenberg.org/contact or http://www.gutenberg.org/5/5/2/0/55201/
Am using the below commands

```
cat filename | grep grep / ((www\.)?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/?)[^\s\b\n|]*[^.,;:\?\!\@\^\$ -])
```

But this is throwing me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for all addresses that start with **http/https/www** -

```
grep -Eo '(http|https|www)(.|://)[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*' fileName
```

Test it and let us know if it solved your problem. I'm not going into the regex details to keep this answer short.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked.

Comment: But have one doubt here.. Can you please explain me [a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-] part. Am not getting why to use =

Comment: consider marking the answer as solved and help future users :)

Comment: cause many web addresses contain '=', for example, this page has a portion `noredirect=1#comment1086020` at the end of its address bar